# Converting a char array to an int value by using atoi in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am quite new to coding in C++ and I am facing a problem right now. I need to write a function that receives a birthdate (string) in a DD.MM.YYYY format as a parameter. I then need to extract the date, month and year and save them in an int-array by using the atoi() function.
My problem in my code is that I get 0 as a value when I use atoi to get the date and the month, but I get the correct value when trying to get the year as a int value. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout, std::cin, std::string;

int * extractDate(string birthday)  //Birthday format: DD.MM.YYYY
{
    // Extraction of DD
    char dayArr[2] = {birthday[0], birthday[1]};
    dayArr[2] = '\0';
    // Extraction of MM
    char monthArr[2] = {birthday[3], birthday[4]};
    monthArr[2] = '\0';
    // Extraction of YYYY
    char yearArr[4] = {birthday[6], birthday[7], birthday[8], birthday[9]};
    yearArr[4] = '\0';
    // Int-Array to save the data as numbers
    int * birthdayArr = new int[3];

    // Converting and saving the data to integers
    birthdayArr[0] = atoi(dayArr);    // Here I get 0
    birthdayArr[1] = atoi(monthArr);  // Here I get 0 as well
    birthdayArr[2] = atoi(yearArr);   // Here I get the year correctly
    birthdayArr[3] = '\0';

    return birthdayArr;
}
```

Comment: There is no `dayArr[2]`. The array only has 2 elements, `dayArr[0]` and `dayArr[1]`.

Comment: `dayArr` has two elements, `dayArr[0]` and `dayArr[1]`.  But `dayArr[2]` is off the end, and assigning to it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you have to do this using `atoi()` instead of a C++ function that takes a `std::string`?

Comment: I tried that at first, but I got completely random numbers. And then I read somewhere here that I need to manually terminate the array myself.

Comment: Yes, you do need to terminate the array yourself. But you also need to declare the array large enough to hold the terminator.

Comment: Because that's how the prof wants it. @Barmar

Comment: Why not use `string::substr()` and `string::c_str()`?

Comment: I rolled back your edit because you basically just changed it to our answers.

Comment: Haha, I am sorry. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Xhuliano `int * birthdayArr = new int[3];` -- Then you did this: `birthdayArr[3] = '\0';` -- This is a memory overwrite.  Also, is this really how they're teaching C++ in your class?  Write code that has potential memory leaks?

Comment: I just recently added the line with the termination, that's why I didn't pay attention to the index. This was my fault, they teach us well, no worries.

Comment: *they teach us well, no worries* -- If this is an example of how they're teaching C++, there are worries.

Comment: It would be much better to just use `sscanf()` or `std::regex()` to extract the 3 integers at one time instead of parsing the string manually. Or, at the very least, use an `std::istringstream` with `operator>>` to extract the integers.

Comment: @Giuliano You forgot one big piece of information -- exactly what does the string look like.  You only put in comments something, but you actually need to show real code as to what the string will contain.  This `DD.MM.YYYY` -- are there `.` in-between the values?  Or is the string really `DDMMYYYY`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll remember that in the future. In this case we have to use the atoi function, because that's how the prof wants it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, there are points in between. Thats why I am skipping an element of birthday in the monthArr and yearArr.

Comment: @Giuliano -- [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69143a16d1ae0a47).

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the arrays large enough to hold the null terminator. You're writing the null byte outside the arrays.

```
    char dayArr[3] = {birthday[0], birthday[1], '\0'};
```

and similarly for the other two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing past the end of your arrays when you're trying to set the last element of them to '\0'. Since dayArr has a length of 2, its valid indices are only 0 and 1--when you try to write to dayArr[2], you're actually writing to whatever is after it in memory, which is (usually) the next variable you declared in the function.

If you increase the size of your arrays by 1 each they should work.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Remember that in C++ (and C), arrays are indexed starting from 0, so when you have dayArr with 3 elements, those elements are numbered 0, 1, 2. So to get the last element of dayArr you would use dayArr[2]

Comment: True, I forgot about that. Thank you

Comment: @Xhuliano Please do not change the code in your question to apply corrections suggested in answers! This renders your question and the existing answers useless for future visitors having the same problem as you. Ty.